# Removing old Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3 throwing error verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate in Ubuntu Part 2

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, openssl

This post only contains the missing list of ca-certs from this post: [Removing old Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3 throwing error verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate in Ubuntu Part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71612999/removing-old-digital-signature-trust-co-cn-dst-root-ca-x3-throwing-error-verify)

I needed to do this because Stackoverflow has a limit of 30000 character per post and I couldn´t do it just in one.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 Mar 25 05:14 8d86cdd1.0 -> certSIGN_ROOT_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 Mar 25 05:14 9007ae68.0 -> CA_Disig_Root_R1.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 Mar 25 05:14 9168f543.0 -> Certplus_Root_CA_G1.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     35 Mar 25 05:14 91739615.0 -> EE_Certification_Centre_Root_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Mar 25 05:14 9282e51c.0 -> CFCA_EV_ROOT.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     34 Mar 25 05:14 930ac5d2.0 -> Actalis_Authentication_Root_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 Mar 25 05:14 9339512a.0 -> QuoVadis_Root_CA_3.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     26 Mar 25 05:14 93bc0acc.0 -> AffirmTrust_Networking.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     63 Mar 25 05:14 9479c8c3.0 -> Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_ECC_RootCA_2015.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 Mar 25 05:14 9576d26b.0 -> CA_Disig_Root_R2.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     29 Mar 25 05:14 95aff9e3.0 -> Certum_Trusted_Network_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     27 Mar 25 05:14 9685a493.0 -> Hongkong_Post_Root_CA_1.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     44 Mar 25 05:14 9772ca32.0 -> GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     48 Mar 25 05:14 988a38cb.0 -> NetLock_Arany_=Class_Gold=_Főtanúsítvány.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25 Mar 25 05:14 9ab62355.0 -> Swisscom_Root_EV_CA_2.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     26 Mar 25 05:14 9c2e7d30.0 -> Sonera_Class_2_Root_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     24 Mar 25 05:14 9c3323d4.0 -> OpenTrust_Root_CA_G1.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     27 Mar 25 05:14 9c8dfbd4.0 -> AffirmTrust_Premium_ECC.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     31 Mar 25 05:14 9d04f354.0 -> DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_G2.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     37 Mar 25 05:14 9d520b32.0 -> Security_Communication_EV_RootCA1.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     37 Mar 25 05:14 9d6523ce.0 -> ePKI_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     37 Mar 25 05:14 9dbefe7b.0 -> Security_Communication_EV_RootCA1.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     24 Mar 25 05:14 9f0f5fd6.0 -> Certinomis_-_Root_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     34 Mar 25 05:14 9f533518.0 -> Global_Chambersign_Root_-_2008.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     38 Mar 25 05:14 a0bc6fbb.0 -> Camerfirma_Global_Chambersign_Root.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     28 Mar 25 05:14 a2c66da8.0 -> DigiCert_Trusted_Root_G4.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     33 Mar 25 05:14 a2df7ad7.0 -> AddTrust_Public_Services_Root.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     34 Mar 25 05:14 a3896b44.0 -> Security_Communication_Root_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     26 Mar 25 05:14 a7605362.0 -> Sonera_Class_2_Root_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 Mar 25 05:14 a760e1bd.0 -> Visa_eCommerce_Root.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     31 Mar 25 05:14 a7d2cf64.0 -> thawte_Primary_Root_CA_-_G2.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19 Mar 25 05:14 a81e292b.0 -> SZAFIR_ROOT_CA2.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     13 Mar 25 05:14 a94d09e5.0 -> ACCVRAIZ1.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 Mar 25 05:14 ab5346f4.0 -> SecureSign_RootCA11.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     48 Mar  1 07:20 ACCVRAIZ1.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/ACCVRAIZ1.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     52 Mar  1 07:20 ACEDICOM_Root.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/ACEDICOM_Root.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     55 Mar  1 07:20 AC_RAIZ_FNMT-RCM.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AC_RAIZ_FNMT-RCM.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     69 Mar  1 07:20 Actalis_Authentication_Root_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Actalis_Authentication_Root_CA.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25 Mar 25 05:14 ad088e1d.0 -> GeoTrust_Universal_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     61 Mar  1 07:20 AddTrust_External_Root.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     71 Mar  1 07:20 AddTrust_Low-Value_Services_Root.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AddTrust_Low-Value_Services_Root.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     68 Mar  1 07:20 AddTrust_Public_Services_Root.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AddTrust_Public_Services_Root.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     75 Mar  1 07:20 AddTrust_Qualified_Certificates_Root.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AddTrust_Qualified_Certificates_Root.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     10 Mar 25 05:14 aeb67534.0 -> EC-ACC.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     45 Mar 25 05:14 aee5f10d.0 -> Entrust.net_Premium_2048_Secure_Server_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     61 Mar  1 07:20 AffirmTrust_Commercial.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AffirmTrust_Commercial.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     61 Mar  1 07:20 AffirmTrust_Networking.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AffirmTrust_Networking.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     62 Mar  1 07:20 AffirmTrust_Premium_ECC.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AffirmTrust_Premium_ECC.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     58 Mar  1 07:20 AffirmTrust_Premium.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AffirmTrust_Premium.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     55 Mar  1 07:20 Amazon_Root_CA_1.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Amazon_Root_CA_1.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     55 Mar  1 07:20 Amazon_Root_CA_2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Amazon_Root_CA_2.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     55 Mar  1 07:20 Amazon_Root_CA_3.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Amazon_Root_CA_3.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     55 Mar  1 07:20 Amazon_Root_CA_4.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Amazon_Root_CA_4.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     60 Mar  1 07:20 Atos_TrustedRoot_2011.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Atos_TrustedRoot_2011.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     96 Mar  1 07:20 Autoridad_de_Certificacion_Firmaprofesional_CIF_A62634068.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Autoridad_de_Certificacion_Firmaprofesional_CIF_A62634068.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     31 Mar 25 05:14 b0e59380.0 -> GlobalSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_R4.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 Mar 25 05:14 b0ed035a.0 -> TWCA_Global_Root_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 Mar 25 05:14 b0f3e76e.0 -> GlobalSign_Root_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     31 Mar 25 05:14 b1159c4c.0 -> DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     34 Mar 25 05:14 b13cc6df.0 -> UTN_USERFirst_Hardware_Root_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     35 Mar 25 05:14 b1b8a7f3.0 -> OISTE_WISeKey_Global_Root_GA_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     64 Mar 25 05:14 b204d74a.0 -> VeriSign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G5.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     46 Mar 25 05:14 b3fb433b.0 -> Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority_-_EC1.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 Mar 25 05:14 b66938e9.0 -> Secure_Global_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 Mar 25 05:14 b727005e.0 -> AffirmTrust_Premium.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     37 Mar 25 05:14 b7a5b843.0 -> TWCA_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     37 Mar 25 05:14 b7db1890.0 -> TWCA_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25 Mar 25 05:14 b872f2b4.0 -> Atos_TrustedRoot_2011.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 Mar 25 05:14 b936d1c6.0 -> AC_RAIZ_FNMT-RCM.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     31 Mar 25 05:14 ba89ed3b.0 -> thawte_Primary_Root_CA_-_G3.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     64 Mar  1 07:20 Baltimore_CyberTrust_Root.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Baltimore_CyberTrust_Root.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     44 Mar 25 05:14 bc3f2570.0 -> Go_Daddy_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 Mar 25 05:14 bd1910d4.0 -> CNNIC_ROOT.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 Mar 25 05:14 bdacca6f.0 -> Secure_Global_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     40 Mar 25 05:14 bf64f35b.0 -> Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     62 Mar  1 07:20 Buypass_Class_2_Root_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Buypass_Class_2_Root_CA.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     62 Mar  1 07:20 Buypass_Class_3_Root_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Buypass_Class_3_Root_CA.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     51 Mar 25 05:14 c01cdfa2.0 -> VeriSign_Universal_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     31 Mar 25 05:14 c089bbbd.0 -> thawte_Primary_Root_CA_-_G2.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     64 Mar 25 05:14 c0ff1f52.0 -> Verisign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     34 Mar 25 05:14 c28a8a30.0 -> D-TRUST_Root_Class_3_CA_2_2009.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     36 Mar 25 05:14 c47d9980.0 -> Chambers_of_Commerce_Root_-_2008.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     31 Mar 25 05:14 c491639e.0 -> DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_G3.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 Mar 25 05:14 c51c224c.0 -> Trustis_FPS_Root_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 Mar 25 05:14 c5d3212a.0 -> PSCProcert.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     49 Mar 25 05:14 c7e2a638.0 -> GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     26 Mar 25 05:14 c907e29b.0 -> LuxTrust_Global_Root_2.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     27 Mar 25 05:14 c90bc37d.0 -> DigiCert_Global_Root_G2.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     31 Mar 25 05:14 c9f83a1c.0 -> Comodo_Secure_Services_root.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     37 Mar 25 05:14 ca6e4ad9.0 -> ePKI_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 232194 Mar 25 05:14 ca-certificates.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     55 Mar  1 07:20 CA_Disig_Root_R1.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/CA_Disig_Root_R1.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     55 Mar  1 07:20 CA_Disig_Root_R2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/CA_Disig_Root_R2.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     75 Mar  1 07:20 Camerfirma_Chambers_of_Commerce_Root.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Camerfirma_Chambers_of_Commerce_Root.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     73 Mar  1 07:20 Camerfirma_Global_Chambersign_Root.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Camerfirma_Global_Chambersign_Root.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     35 Mar 25 05:14 cb156124.0 -> E-Tugra_Certification_Authority.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     31 Mar 25 05:14 cb1c3204.0 -> Certum_Trusted_Network_CA_2.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     38 Mar 25 05:14 cb59f961.0 -> Camerfirma_Global_Chambersign_Root.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     24 Mar 25 05:14 cbeee9e2.0 -> GeoTrust_Global_CA_2.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     44 Mar 25 05:14 cbf06781.0 -> Go_Daddy_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 Mar 25 05:14 cc450945.0 -> Izenpe.com.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     27 Mar 25 05:14 ccc52f49.0 -> AffirmTrust_Premium_ECC.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     34 Mar 25 05:14 cd58d51e.0 -> Security_Communication_RootCA2.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 Mar 25 05:14 cd8c0d63.0 -> AC_RAIZ_FNMT-RCM.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 Mar 25 05:14 ce5e74ef.0 -> Amazon_Root_CA_1.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     47 Mar  1 07:20 Certigna.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Certigna.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     68 Mar  1 07:20 Certinomis_-_Autorité_Racine.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Certinomis_-_Autorité_Racine.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     59 Mar  1 07:20 Certinomis_-_Root_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Certinomis_-_Root_CA.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     66 Mar  1 07:20 Certplus_Class_2_Primary_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Certplus_Class_2_Primary_CA.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     58 Mar  1 07:20 Certplus_Root_CA_G1.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Certplus_Root_CA_G1.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     58 Mar  1 07:20 Certplus_Root_CA_G2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Certplus_Root_CA_G2.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     55 Mar  1 07:20 certSIGN_ROOT_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/certSIGN_ROOT_CA.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     53 Mar  1 07:20 Certum_Root_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Certum_Root_CA.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     66 Mar  1 07:20 Certum_Trusted_Network_CA_2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Certum_Trusted_Network_CA_2.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     64 Mar  1 07:20 Certum_Trusted_Network_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Certum_Trusted_Network_CA.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     18 Mar 25 05:14 cf701eeb.0 -> SecureTrust_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     51 Mar  1 07:20 CFCA_EV_ROOT.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/CFCA_EV_ROOT.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     71 Mar  1 07:20 Chambers_of_Commerce_Root_-_2008.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Chambers_of_Commerce_Root_-_2008.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    101 Mar  1 07:20 China_Internet_Network_Information_Center_EV_Certificates_Root.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/China_Internet_Network_Information_Center_EV_Certificates_Root.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     49 Mar  1 07:20 CNNIC_ROOT.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/CNNIC_ROOT.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     63 Mar  1 07:20 Comodo_AAA_Services_root.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Comodo_AAA_Services_root.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     69 Mar  1 07:20 COMODO_Certification_Authority.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/COMODO_Certification_Authority.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     73 Mar  1 07:20 COMODO_ECC_Certification_Authority.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/COMODO_ECC_Certification_Authority.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     73 Mar  1 07:20 COMODO_RSA_Certification_Authority.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/COMODO_RSA_Certification_Authority.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     66 Mar  1 07:20 Comodo_Secure_Services_root.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Comodo_Secure_Services_root.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     67 Mar  1 07:20 Comodo_Trusted_Services_root.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Comodo_Trusted_Services_root.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     61 Mar  1 07:20 Cybertrust_Global_Root.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Cybertrust_Global_Root.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     32 Mar 25 05:14 d06393bb.0 -> T-TeleSec_GlobalRoot_Class_2.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     61 Mar 25 05:14 d16a5865.0 -> Autoridad_de_Certificacion_Firmaprofesional_CIF_A62634068.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     34 Mar 25 05:14 d18e9066.0 -> IdenTrust_Commercial_Root_CA_1.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 Mar 25 05:14 d41b5e2a.0 -> Amazon_Root_CA_4.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     38 Mar 25 05:14 d4c339cb.0 -> COMODO_RSA_Certification_Authority.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     37 Mar 25 05:14 d4dae3dd.0 -> D-TRUST_Root_Class_3_CA_2_EV_2009.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     34 Mar 25 05:14 d59297b8.0 -> Security_Communication_RootCA2.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     38 Mar 25 05:14 d6325660.0 -> COMODO_RSA_Certification_Authority.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     53 Mar 25 05:14 d66b55d9.0 -> TURKTRUST_Certificate_Services_Provider_Root_2007.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     24 Mar 25 05:14 d6e6eab9.0 -> Certinomis_-_Root_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     37 Mar 25 05:14 d7746a63.0 -> D-TRUST_Root_Class_3_CA_2_EV_2009.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 Mar 25 05:14 d7e8dc79.0 -> QuoVadis_Root_CA_2.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 Mar 25 05:14 d8317ada.0 -> Certplus_Root_CA_G2.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 Mar 25 05:14 d853d49e.0 -> Trustis_FPS_Root_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     33 Mar 25 05:14 d957f522.0 -> Certinomis_-_Autorité_Racine.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 Mar 25 05:14 dbc54cab.0 -> AffirmTrust_Premium.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     59 Mar 25 05:14 dc99f41e.0 -> Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_RootCA_2015.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     27 Mar 25 05:14 dd8e9d41.0 -> DigiCert_Global_Root_G3.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 Mar 25 05:14 de6d66f3.0 -> Amazon_Root_CA_4.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     26 Mar 25 05:14 def36a68.0 -> LuxTrust_Global_Root_2.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     65 Mar  1 07:20 Deutsche_Telekom_Root_CA_2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Deutsche_Telekom_Root_CA_2.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     35 Mar 25 05:14 dfc0fe80.0 -> OISTE_WISeKey_Global_Root_GB_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     66 Mar  1 07:20 DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_CA.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     66 Mar  1 07:20 DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_G2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_G2.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     66 Mar  1 07:20 DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_G3.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_G3.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     62 Mar  1 07:20 DigiCert_Global_Root_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/DigiCert_Global_Root_CA.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     62 Mar  1 07:20 DigiCert_Global_Root_G2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/DigiCert_Global_Root_G2.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     62 Mar  1 07:20 DigiCert_Global_Root_G3.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/DigiCert_Global_Root_G3.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     73 Mar  1 07:20 DigiCert_High_Assurance_EV_Root_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/DigiCert_High_Assurance_EV_Root_CA.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     63 Mar  1 07:20 DigiCert_Trusted_Root_G4.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/DigiCert_Trusted_Root_G4.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     53 Mar  1 07:20 DST_ACES_CA_X6.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/DST_ACES_CA_X6.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     69 Mar  1 07:20 D-TRUST_Root_Class_3_CA_2_2009.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/D-TRUST_Root_Class_3_CA_2_2009.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     72 Mar  1 07:20 D-TRUST_Root_Class_3_CA_2_EV_2009.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/D-TRUST_Root_Class_3_CA_2_EV_2009.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     12 Mar 25 05:14 e113c810.0 -> Certigna.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25 Mar 25 05:14 e18bfb83.0 -> QuoVadis_Root_CA_3_G3.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     36 Mar 25 05:14 e268a4c5.0 -> AddTrust_Low-Value_Services_Root.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     49 Mar 25 05:14 e2799e36.0 -> GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25 Mar 25 05:14 e36a6752.0 -> Atos_TrustedRoot_2011.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25 Mar 25 05:14 e442e424.0 -> QuoVadis_Root_CA_3_G3.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     26 Mar 25 05:14 e48193cf.0 -> AffirmTrust_Commercial.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     40 Mar 25 05:14 e536d871.0 -> AddTrust_Qualified_Certificates_Root.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 Mar 25 05:14 e60bf0c0.0 -> Swisscom_Root_CA_1.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     35 Mar 25 05:14 e73d606e.0 -> OISTE_WISeKey_Global_Root_GB_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25 Mar 25 05:14 e775ed2d.0 -> GeoTrust_Universal_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     34 Mar 25 05:14 e8651083.0 -> Microsec_e-Szigno_Root_CA_2009.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     27 Mar 25 05:14 e8de2f56.0 -> Buypass_Class_3_Root_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     21 Mar 25 05:14 ea014740.0 -> ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     17 Mar 25 05:14 ea169617.0 -> ACEDICOM_Root.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     45 Mar  1 07:20 EC-ACC.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/EC-ACC.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     27 Mar 25 05:14 ed39abd0.0 -> DigiCert_Global_Root_G3.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     28 Mar 25 05:14 ee64a828.0 -> Comodo_AAA_Services_root.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     40 Mar 25 05:14 ee7cd6fb.0 -> Camerfirma_Chambers_of_Commerce_Root.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     70 Mar  1 07:20 EE_Certification_Centre_Root_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/EE_Certification_Centre_Root_CA.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     38 Mar 25 05:14 eed8c118.0 -> COMODO_ECC_Certification_Authority.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     34 Mar 25 05:14 ef954a4e.0 -> IdenTrust_Commercial_Root_CA_1.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     80 Mar  1 07:20 Entrust.net_Premium_2048_Secure_Server_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Entrust.net_Premium_2048_Secure_Server_CA.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     81 Mar  1 07:20 Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority_-_EC1.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority_-_EC1.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     80 Mar  1 07:20 Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority_-_G2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority_-_G2.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     75 Mar  1 07:20 Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     72 Mar  1 07:20 ePKI_Root_Certification_Authority.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/ePKI_Root_Certification_Authority.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     70 Mar  1 07:20 E-Tugra_Certification_Authority.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/E-Tugra_Certification_Authority.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     31 Mar 25 05:14 f060240e.0 -> Certplus_Class_2_Primary_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 Mar 25 05:14 f081611a.0 -> Go_Daddy_Class_2_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     41 Mar 25 05:14 f30dd6ad.0 -> USERTrust_ECC_Certification_Authority.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     34 Mar 25 05:14 f3377b1b.0 -> Security_Communication_Root_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     24 Mar 25 05:14 f387163d.0 -> Starfield_Class_2_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     18 Mar 25 05:14 f39fc864.0 -> SecureTrust_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     40 Mar 25 05:14 f90208f7.0 -> Camerfirma_Chambers_of_Commerce_Root.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     64 Mar 25 05:14 facacbc6.0 -> VeriSign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G5.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 Mar 25 05:14 fb5fa911.0 -> Amazon_Root_CA_2.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     41 Mar 25 05:14 fc5a8f99.0 -> USERTrust_RSA_Certification_Authority.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 Mar 25 05:14 fd08c599.0 -> Amazon_Root_CA_1.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     12 Mar 25 05:14 fde84897.0 -> Certigna.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19 Mar 25 05:14 fe8a2cd8.0 -> SZAFIR_ROOT_CA2.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     49 Mar 25 05:14 ff34af3f.0 -> TUBITAK_Kamu_SM_SSL_Kok_Sertifikasi_-_Surum_1.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     34 Mar 25 05:14 ff783690.0 -> UTN_USERFirst_Hardware_Root_CA.pem
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     59 Mar  1 07:20 GeoTrust_Global_CA_2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GeoTrust_Global_CA_2.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     57 Mar  1 07:20 GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GeoTrust_Global_CA.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     84 Mar  1 07:20 GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G2.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     84 Mar  1 07:20 GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     79 Mar  1 07:20 GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     62 Mar  1 07:20 GeoTrust_Universal_CA_2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GeoTrust_Universal_CA_2.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     60 Mar  1 07:20 GeoTrust_Universal_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GeoTrust_Universal_CA.crt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     69 Mar  1 07:20 Global_Chambersign_Root_-_2008.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Global_Chambersign_Root_-_2008.crt
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not actually a question. It is simply spread a single question over multiple ones and this is the second part of it. Please note that each question at SO should be self-contained, so this is clearly not how SO was intended to be used. If your extensive information do not fit into a single question use services like pastebin for the details.

Comment: Steffen this is the only way to provide the complete list of ca certificates as stackoverflow is limiting the number of characters and I cannot provide it just in one post. This is just for debugging purposes.